# What is the sum of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any procedure or formula to calculate the sum?

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{\pi}$$

Comment: That looks divergent to me

Comment: It sums up to infinity

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do an analytic comtinuation of the Riemann zeta function to an argument of $-\pi$.  People often do that with the argument $-1$ and claim that $1+2+3+4+...=-1/{12}$.  Formulas with which to do that are given in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function, specifically the Representations section.

BUT ...

Do not forget that the zeta function is defined by the familiar sum-of-powers formula *only if* that sum converges.  You can get a number from the representations alluded to above and call it $\zeta(-\pi)$, but that does not  mean you can call it the sum of a divergent series.

Comment: Good job mentioning both sides of the coin.

Answer (score 0):

for each $N>0$,
$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N n^\pi \geq\sum_{k=1}^N 1 \geq N$.

when $N \to +\infty$,

$S_N $ goes also to $+\infty$.